# Missing "Delivered-To" header in qmail

Tags: email

The `man qmail-local` page states that the `Delivered-To` header is always added to the email.

For some reason, however, many of my emails are missing it. Namely, those that are sent to users created in "users/assign" using the wildcard notation.

Is this a bug, or are these delivered bypassing `qmail-local`? How else can I tell which of the wildcard addresses the email was actually delivered to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The trick is to duplicate the `.qmail` file as `.qmaildefault` (or symlink, though I haven't tested if this works).

Longer version: the rule in `users/assign` is set up as follows:

```
+prefix:popuser:123:456:/path/to/mailbox:::
```

`man qmail-users` describes the last two parts as "dash" and "pre" without really explaining what they do (or assuming that you pretty much know the ins and outs of qmail). Neither does [life with qmail](http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#qmail-users), but it gives a useful hint about how the `.qmail` file name is constructed.

Since the "dash" part of the rule is blank, the `.qmail` and `default` parts are concatenated without any separators.

I still have no idea why it doesn't fall back onto the `.qmail` name -